# how to delete all the rows if all the corresponding ids are same in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
id|number
12|c
21|e
31|a
43|a
43|a
43|b
52|x
52|x
52|x
53|d
```

In the above example, I want to keep all the rows corresponding to 43 and delete all belonging to 52.

Comment: What about 12 and 21 and 31? Explain what exactly is being deleted and why that is.

Comment: Only delete once belonging to 52, keep the rest

Comment: I can't add a unique index that'd delete 43|a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using aggregation logic here:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    t1.id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM yourTable
                              GROUP BY id
                              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT number) = 1) x);
```

The restriction `COUNT(*) > 1` ensures that the `id` has at least two records, while `COUNT(DISTINCT number) = 1` ensures that this `id` has the same number value for all duplicates.  We wrap the subquery once to avoid any possible MySQL errors about referring to a table while it is being deleted.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, could you please help me with a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981959/simply-mysql-and-filter-delete-by-joins

Comment: I upvoted it a while. let me check how accepting works

Answer (score 0):

This should delete all rows corresponding to 52. Those with 43 and other ids will remain in the table.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 52;
```

There are basic operations; you will do well to read through some [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

**Update**: if you wish to delete only rows that correspond to duplicate id and number combination, you might try the below SQL. It uses the concatenation of id and the number to determine duplicates to remove.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT id from (
      select concat(id,'-',number) as connum from table_name
      group by connum
      having connum > 1
    )
  )
```

Comment: This is not exactly what OP meant. He meant *how to delete rows that, for a specific id, has only the same number*. 52 was an example