# how to delete mysql rows using joins

Tags: python, mysql

```
c2.execute("delete from entity_map where canon_id in (select canon_id from
entity_map_session where canon_id in (select canon_id from 
entity_map_session group by canon_id having count(canon_id) < 10))")
```

I want to speed up the above set of operations. Especially the last one where we delete rows. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Deechau The answer to your follow-up question generally is that if you need to do this aggregation-filtering, then there aren't any good ways to speed it up.  That being said, if you can handle it in a single step while creating your table, versus two separate steps for creation and deletion, then you should go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery against the `entity_map_session2` table is doing a count aggregation, and has no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, which means that it cannot be optimized much.  However, you may do away with one of the unnecessary nested subqueries, e.g. use:

```
DELETE
FROM entity_map2
WHERE canon_id IN (SELECT canon_id FROM entity_map_session2
                   GROUP BY canon_id HAVING COUNT(canon_id) < 10);
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do while creating entity_map_session2 to avoid that last step of deletion?

Comment: You have dramatically changed your question, thereby invalidating all answers given.  I can't help much at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Delete from table use join should be next:

```
delete entity_map2.*
from entity_map2 
join (
    select canon_id 
    from entity_map_session2 
    group by canon_id having count(canon_id) < 10
) a on a.canon_id = entity_map2.canon_id;
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen you absolutely right. I just updated my query

Answer (score -1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2;
```

Comment: `DROP TABLE` does not remove rows, it remove whole table